# B-spline - rought ''connection'' between curves

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, bezier, bspline

Take a look a picture below.

White square is a shared control point between 2 b-curves which are part of the same spline.

I am generating a mesh around that spline that will act as a floor, but between every ''curves'' of my b-spline the junction is pretty harsh (see picture) and there is overlapping and/or derivative is pretty high which make the path not so soft.

What should I try to soften the result and reduce the overlapping?

[image]

Comment: Aren't you missing a picture in your question? Without it I can't make sense of it.

Comment: Changed question - need help on something more precise

Comment: Since you only have two white squares in the picture, which means you only show two control points are shown. So, I still cannot figure out the rest of control points and the two B-spline curves.